# Simple example of CuDnnGRU based RNN implementation in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am using the following code for standard GRU implementation:

```
def BiRNN_deep_dynamic_FAST_FULL_autolength(x,batch_size,dropout,hidden_dim):

seq_len=length_rnn(x)

with tf.variable_scope('forward'):
    lstm_cell_fwd =tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(hidden_dim,kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),bias_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    lstm_cell_fwd = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell_fwd, output_keep_prob=dropout)
with tf.variable_scope('backward'):
    lstm_cell_back =tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(hidden_dim,kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),bias_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    lstm_cell_back = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell_back, output_keep_prob=dropout)

outputs,_= tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw=lstm_cell_fwd,cell_bw= lstm_cell_back,inputs=x,sequence_length=seq_len,dtype=tf.float32,time_major=False)
outputs_fwd,outputs_bck=outputs

### fwd matrix is the matrix that keeps all the last [-1] vectors
fwd_matrix=tf.gather_nd(outputs_fwd, tf.stack([tf.range(batch_size), seq_len-1], axis=1))       ###  99,64

outputs_fwd=tf.transpose(outputs_fwd,[1,0,2])
outputs_bck=tf.transpose(outputs_bck,[1,0,2])

return outputs_fwd,outputs_bck,fwd_matrix
```

Can anyone provide a simple example of how to use the tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnGRU Cell in a similar fashion? Just swapping out the cells doesn't work.

First issue is that there is no dropout wrapper for CuDnnGRU cell, which is fine. Second it doesnt seem to work with tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CudnnGRU` is not an `RNNCell` instance. It's more akin to `dynamic_rnn`.

The tensor manipulations below are equivalent, where `input_tensor` is a time-major tensor, i.e. of shape `[max_sequence_length, batch_size, embedding_size]`. CudnnGRU expects the input tensor to be time-major (as opposed to the more standard batch-major format i.e. of shape `[batch_size, max_sequence_length, embedding_size]`), and it's a good practice to use time-major tensors with RNN ops anyways since they're somewhat faster.

CudnnGRU:

```
rnn = tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnGRU(
  num_rnn_layers, hidden_size, direction='bidirectional')

rnn_output = rnn(input_tensor)
```

CudnnCompatibleGRUCell:

```
rnn_output = input_tensor
sequence_length = tf.reduce_sum(
  tf.sign(inputs),
  reduction_indices=0)  # 1 if `input_tensor` is batch-major.

  for _ in range(num_rnn_layers):
    fw_cell = tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnCompatibleGRUCell(hidden_size)
    bw_cell = tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnCompatibleGRUCell(hidden_size)
    rnn_output = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
      fw_cell, bw_cell, rnn_output, sequence_length=sequence_length,
      dtype=tf.float32, time_major=True)[1]  # Set `time_major` accordingly
```

Note the following:

1. If you were using LSTMs, you need not use `CudnnCompatibleLSTMCell`; you can use the standard `LSTMCell`. But with GRUs, the Cudnn implementation has inherently different math operations, and in particular, more weights ([see the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/cudnn_rnn/CudnnCompatibleGRUCell)).
2. Unlike `dynamic_rnn`, `CudnnGRU` doesn't allow you to specify sequence lengths. Still, it is over an order of magnitude faster, but you will have to be careful on how you extract your outputs (e.g. if you're interested in the final hidden state of each sequence that is padded and of varying length, you will need each sequence's length).
3. `rnn_output` is probably a tuple with lots of (distinct) stuff in both cases. Refer to the documentation, or just print it out, to inspect what parts of the output you need.