# Unexpected results with CuDNNLSTM (instead of LSTM) layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I have posted this question as an [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13022) in Keras' Github but figured it might reach a broader audience here.

---

**System information**

- Have I written custom code (as opposed to using example directory):  **Minimal change to official Keras tutorial**
- OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04):  **Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS**
- TensorFlow backend (yes / no):  **yes**
- TensorFlow version:  **1.13.1**
- Keras version:  **2.2.4**
- Python version:  **3.6.5**
- CUDA/cuDNN version:  **10.1**
- GPU model and memory:  **Tesla K80 11G**

**Describe the current behavior**
I am executing the code from the Seq2Seq [tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/lstm_seq2seq/). The one and only change I made was to swap the **LSTM** layers for **CuDNNLSTM**. What happens is that the model predicts a fixed output for any input I give it. When I run the original code, I get sensible results.

**Describe the expected behavior**
See preceding section.

**Code to reproduce the issue**
Taken from [here](https://keras.io/examples/lstm_seq2seq/). Simply replace LSTM with CuDNNLSTM.

---

Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here there are two problems.
Use of `CuDNNLSTM` and `parameter tuning`.
Basically, the network overfits on your dataset which leads the output being only one sentence for every input. This is neither the fault of `CuDNNLSTM` nor `LSTM`.

Firstly,
`CuDNN` has a bit different maths from regular `LSTM` to make it Cuda Compatible and run faster. The `LSTM` takes 11 sec to run on eng-hindi file for the same code that you used and `CuDNNLSTM` takes 1 sec for each epoch.

In the CuDNNLSTM `time_major` param is set to `false`. For this reason the network overfits. You can check it [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.14/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/cudnn_recurrent.py).
You can clearly see for small datasets like eng-hin or eng-marathi the `val-loss` increases after 30 epochs. There is no point in running the network more where your `network loss` is decreasing and `val_loss` is increasing. The case with `LSTM` is same too.

Here you need `param tuning` for small datasets.

Here are a few links which can help:

1. [Eng-Mar](https://towardsdatascience.com/word-level-english-to-marathi-neural-machine-translation-using-seq2seq-encoder-decoder-lstm-model-1a913f2dc4a7)
2. [Pytorch translation tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/seq2seq_translation_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-intermediate-seq2seq-translation-tutorial-py)
3. [Similar Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183538/simple-example-of-cudnngru-based-rnn-implementation-in-tensorflow/51158186#51158186) and [Similar Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54559111/different-results-while-training-with-cudnnlstm-compared-to-regular-lstmcell-in)
4. [NMT-keras](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/01/neural-machine-translation-keras/)

Comment: It appears that the small dataset size was indeed the issue. I re-run the experiment with a much larger dataset and was able to get very good results. Thanks!